# HTML Tooltips display property

Tags: html, css, tooltip, xslt-1.0

I am using `tooltip` inside a column of a table in `HTML`.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        THE FIRST COLUMN
    </td>
    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">3</xsl:attribute>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                HERE IS THE TEXT.
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                ( TOOLTIP TEXT )
            </span>
        </div>
    </xsl:element>
</tr>
```

When I am using the following code for the `tooltip`:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I am using `background-color: gray;` for the column of table. What is my problem is that the color is till end of text and then the rest is white. When I am commenting `display: inline-block` then it is only around the text but I would like to fit color in whole the table.

**Update:**

Here is a  figure after creating HTML. As you see my problem remains(not thw whole cell is colored, rather BG of text.). I could not use the global `back-ground-color`, because I have different colors depend on the condition when it is fulfilled.
[(screenShot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWmd9.jpg)

```
<xsl:element name="td">
    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">3</xsl:attribute>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
             <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='PASS'">passline</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>logline</xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                HERE IS THE TEXT.
            </span>
    </div>
</xsl:element>

#passline { background-color: lime; }
#logline { background-color: #D8D8D8 ; }
```

Comment: @MrLister exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot. Would you please send it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to color the whole cell, you will need to change the markup so that you can target the cell specifically with CSS. Preferably with a class, so that would become

```xml
<xsl:element name="td">
    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">3</xsl:attribute>
    <!-- new XSL here -->
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="attribute::type='PASS'">passline</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>logline</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- until here -->
    <div class="tooltip">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
             <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='PASS'">passline</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>logline</xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                HERE IS THE TEXT.
            </span>
    </div>
</xsl:element>
```

and then you can use

```css
.passline { background-color: lime; }
.logline { background-color: #D8D8D8 ; }
```

in the CSS.

(Note I used the same names for the classes you used for the ids, but you can change those to your liking of course.)

---

(Older solution here. For ever older answers see edit history.)
Assuming that the tooltip can take up the whole of the table cell, that is, there isn't anything else in the cell, we can use a little trick to make it look like the whole cell has the tooltip's background color: position the tooltip absolutely in the cell. Expand it to use the same area as the cell by setting `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` all to 0.

If the generated HTML looks anything like the below, this CSS will do it.
(Sorry, but the stacksnippet can't do XSLT yet; I had to translate to HTML myself.)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
}
#passline { background-color: lime; }
#logline { background-color: #D8D8D8; }
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - .6em); left: 2px;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
td {
  border-top: 1px solid; border-left: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left-width: 2px;
  width: 10em;
}
td:not(:empty) { padding: .5em 2px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>LOG<br>
        11:08 12:01:49</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="tooltip" id="logline">
        <span class="tooltiptext">test tooltip Reset</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LOG<br>
        11:08 12:01:49</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="tooltip" id="passline">
        <span class="tooltiptext">test tooltip Reset</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now this CSS has a bit of a disadvantage: it won't work properly under IE. Not sure why.
If IE compatibility is an issue, you can solve at the cost of sacrificing some flexibility: give the tooltips an explicit height, the same as the height of the table cells. In the example, it will have to become 3.4em (2 × 1.2em for the two lines of text and 2 × .5em for the cell padding). The rest of the code can stay the same.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height:3.4em;
}
#passline { background-color: lime; }
#logline { background-color: #D8D8D8; }
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - .6em); left: 2px;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
td {
  border-top: 1px solid; border-left: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left-width: 2px;
  width: 10em;
}
td:not(:empty) { padding: .5em 2px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>LOG<br>
        11:08 12:01:49</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="tooltip" id="logline">
        <span class="tooltiptext">test tooltip Reset</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LOG<br>
        11:08 12:01:49</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="tooltip" id="passline">
        <span class="tooltiptext">test tooltip Reset</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Would you please take a look at the "Update" above. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so what is the condition? What is different about the table rows in which the background needs to be green? Do they have classes, IDs, roles?

Comment: OK, I added a new solution based on the new criteria. Is this how you want it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect answer(I could not give +1 under 15 rep. :( )!

Comment: I just noticed that because position is `position: absolute;` for `tooltip` then for the cells which have more than one line then it will be put in background of other cells because the width is not enough to show them.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to assign an id or a class to the parent `td` elements which you can target with CSS, so that you don't have to do the `absolute` trick.

Comment: May I ask you to give an example please?

Comment: I added an example to the answer with what I hope is correct XSL.

Comment: Yes, for the class attribute on the table cell. So that the cell gets the same class name as the id name on the tooltip.